# Can't access Windows 10 after dual boot

Tags: release-freya, system-installation, dual-boot, microsoft-windows

(First of all, I'm totally new to this)

I've installed elementary OS alongside Windows 10 (shrinking the main partition of windows with a new empty partition of 100GB, and then installed Elementary using an USB flash drive).

elementary OS seems to work perfectly, but i can't access Windows Boot Manager anymore from the GRUB Menu, it says:
[image]

Keep it mind that i'm using a Lenovo laptop (FLex 14-D).

Can you help me please?

Comment: Same problem.Fixed by installng rEFInd

Answer (score 1):

ok I've done boot-repair from a live-usb and now in the grub menu i've these options to choose.

What do i have to do in order to access to Windows?

Also i think i've forgotten to disable Secure Boot at the beginning, is it still necessary after boot-repair.

[SOLVED] better than i thought, it was the first one "Windows UEFI recovery bootmgfw.efi" (don't know why but it works)

Thanks everyone for all the support.

Answer (score 0):

try firing up a console and `sudo grub-update`, then restart and boot windows again.

Comment: i've tried to update grub but it says the same thing.

Comment: then it probably is something windows-related. can you show us `blkid` ?

Comment: done (the picture in the OP)

Comment: i am sorry but you've probably overwritten the windows MBR petition(the system reserved one that costs you 100mb), i'm not really the best when in comes to MS stuff but i'd say you mount your windows main petition, backup your things, and reinstall windows.

Comment: kraken@MichaelShalom:~$ sudo blkid
[sudo] password for kraken: 
/dev/sda1: LABEL="System Reserved" UUID="80D42D64D42D5DA2" TYPE="ntfs" <-you've overwritten this
-------------------------
/dev/sda2: UUID="7A58439F584358D1" TYPE="ntfs" 
-------------------------
/dev/sda4: LABEL="storeage" UUID="82AE2422AE2410E9" TYPE="ntfs" 
-------------------------
/dev/sda5: UUID="40eafe67-64b6-4916-a310-0688a6c17675" TYPE="ext4" 
-------------------------
/dev/sda6: UUID="e9c1e289-075d-449d-90db-a84a11baaeed" TYPE="swap"

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to follow the Boot-repair instructions, available here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

If your Windows 10 partition is still intact you will be fine following the instructions.

Comment: Generally it is good practice to include necessary content here, and link at the end.

Comment: I've tried to run Boot-repair from PPA, but it says to run boot repair from a Live CD or Live USB. (i will try it now).

Comment: I've also noticed on system setup that i'm in UEFI Mode (do i have to change?), and there is a mode called "OS Optimized Defaults" and it is in "Win8 64bit mode". What is it?